# Ajax reload DIV, execute immediately

Tags: ajax, html, reload

I have the following script, it reloads the forum topics every 3 seconds but I also want it to load as soon as the page loads, so that there is no delay the first time. The first time the page loads it takes 3 seconds before the topics show up.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){


function foo()
{
$('#forum').load('forum.php').fadeIn("slow");
} // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
setInterval(foo, 3000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are waiting on the `.onload` event, which is fired when all resources/assets (like images) have been downloaded by the browser — this delay will be significant on bloated or resource-heavy sites, which will make a lot of HTTP requests and does not fire the `onload` event as early as you wish.

The solution? You should instead fire `foo` on DOM ready:

```
$(function() {
    var foo = function() {
        $('#forum').load('forum.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }

    // Will execute on DOM ready
    foo();
    setInterval(foo, 3000);
});
```

Note that `$(function() {...})` is the equivalent of `$(document).ready(function() {...})` in jQuery.

If you wish to also forcibly fire `foo()` when all resources are loaded up, just fire it again with:

```
$(function() {
    var foo = function() {
        $('#forum').load('forum.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }

    // Will execute on DOM ready
    foo();
    setInterval(foo, 3000);

    // Also execute on window load
    $(window).load(foo);
});
```